# Rendering Admin Forms When An Error Occurs in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys, render

I have a model that contains a field with a foreign key and this field can be NULL and is optional. I can save this form in admin page without any problems if this field has no values. However, when there's an error on my form, my form cannot be rendered and Django returns the following error:

```
Caught ValueError while rendering: need more than 0 values to unpack on line 19
9               {% for field in line %}
10                  <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}"{% endif %}>
11                      {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
12                      {% if field.is_checkbox %}
13                          {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
14                      {% else %}
15                          {{ field.label_tag }}
16                          {% if field.is_readonly %}
17                              <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
18                          {% else %}
19                              {{ field.field }}
20                          {% endif %}
21                      {% endif %}
22                      {% if field.field.field.help_text %}
23                          <p class="help">{{ field.field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
24                      {% endif %}
25                  </div>
26              {% endfor %}
27          </div>
28      {% endfor %}
29  </fieldset>
```

Here is how my model looks like:

```
class Circuit(CommonFields):
  """Circuit class model."""
  vid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  vname = models.CharField(
      'Vendor Name',
      max_length=100,
      null=True,
      blank=True)
  vspc = models.ForeignKey(
      Room,
      db_column='avspc',
      verbose_name='Space',
      null=True,
      blank=True)
```

And here is my custom clean() for my custom form:

```
  def clean(self):
    """Custom port range validator."""
    super(CircuitForm, self).clean()
    raise forms.ValidationError("Some stupid error just happened.")
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    return cleaned_data
```

Note that if I remove raise statement, my forms can be submitted successfully, however, when I raise an error, it gives me the above error.

Any ideas how I can render my form when there's an error in it?

Note that this error occurs only when I'm creating a new entry without setting the optional field or when editing an entry that doesn't have the optional fields set. If I'm editing an existing entry which has those optional field set, if I unset the optional fields, it doesn't give any error.

Comment: I actually got it fixed. I was initializing those fields manually in the __init__ method using a dictionary, while I had to use a list of tuples like this: [("", "--Select--")]. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: If you could put that in an answer and then mark it as correct it would help others with similar problems.

Comment: I see a problem in your clean method. you must have forgotten the if clause before raising ValidationError, this clean method will always raise a ValidationError whatever your data are. Maybe just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

@GeoffroyCALA is right, you need condition to raise an exception. If you do not check the condition, exception will be raised anyway. Moreover, you do not specify a form field for which you set the custom exception. See the [docs example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Try something like that:

```
def clean(self):
    """Custom port range validator."""
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    if cleaned_data['vpc'] not in Room.objects.values_list('id', flat=True): # FOR EXAMPLE
        raise forms.ValidationError("Some stupid error just happened.")        

    super(CircuitForm, self).clean()

    return cleaned_data
```